# Что лучше для парсинга JSON в Android

Tags: android

Есть php файл, который возвращает json файл в таком виде. Данных конечно же больше, для простоты оставил только 2 элемента. Необходимо вывести заголовки (поле title) в список, а если нажать на элемент списка, чтобы открывалось описание и другая информация (дата и т.д.).

Какие есть способы реализовать такое? Подойдут ли библиотеки GSON и Retrofit какой из них использовать?

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 96,
      "title": "Заголовок 1",
      "catid": 2,
      "created": "2015-09-14 12:05:45",
      "introtext": "Описание 1"
    },
    {
      "id": 97,
      "title": "Заголовок 2",
      "catid": 2,
      "created": "2015-09-14 12:06:42",
      "introtext": "Описание 2"
    }
  ],
  "success": 1
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`GSON` - библиотека, которая занимается парсингом `JSON` в `Java` и обратно.
`Retrofit` - реализация `REST API` клиента, внутри которого лежит библиотека `OkHttp` (она и занимается самими запросами)
`Retrofit` и `Gson` отлично работают вместе. На эту тему есть огромное количество статей на том же хабре.

В общем набор библиотек следующий - `Retrofit` (внутри лежит `OkHttp`) для похода в сеть, `gson` для парсинга `json` в `java`. Но для парсинга, нужно написать модельный класс, который будет соответствовать приходящему Json'у. Для этого есть сервисы типа http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ - показывает в удобном формате структуру json'a и http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org который на основании json сформирует вам java класс. 
Так же `Retrofit + Gson` отлично дружат с библиотекой `Auto Value Parcel` ( она нужна для авто генерации геттеров /сеттеров и методов типа equals/hashcode у модельных классов) всё это в связке очень сильно облегчит вам жизнь в дальнейшей разработке

Для вашей конкретной задачи алгоритм такой: `Retrofit` идёт в сеть, получает `Json` (внутрь ретрофиту можно запихнуть объект `Gson` который сразу вернет вам из запроса готовый Java модельный класс, его вы должны реализовать сами) Потом это дело стоит записать в Бд или `SharedPreferences`. Затем делаете `RecyclerView` в его `Adapter` засовываете свои объекты из БД, отображаете только Title. (В ресайклер можно грузить не весь объект, а только поле `title`, это для оптимизации работы с БД) а потом при нажатии на элемент списка вытаскиваете из БД полный экземпляр нужного объекта и уже выводите в другом активити/фрагменте)

Comment: спасибо, чуть понятнее стало) будем читать и смотреть примеры

Comment: дополнил ответ. ваша задача вполне стандартна, так что проблем с примерами возникнуть не должно

Comment: Понял алгоритм работы. Спасибо большое.